# Is deleting from binary search tree is symmetric?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

If I delete node x and then node y or delete y and the x, after this deleted I will stay with the same binary search tree?

I tried a few examples and I think that's true.

But how can i prove this?

Comment: Are you storing values in the internal nodes or only in the leaves?

Comment: i have value in all nodes

Answer (score 1):

It's false. Consider the tree

```
  4
 / \
1   5
 \
  2
   \
    3 ,
```

from which 4 and 5 are deleted in some order. If the order is 5 then 4, the result is

```
1
 \
  2
   \
    3 .
```

If the order is 4 then 5, the result could be

```
  3
 /
1
 \
  2 ,
```

assuming that, when we would delete a node with two children, we instead replace its value by that of its in-order predecessor and delete the predecessor. (I'm assuming also the standard deletion procedure for zero- and one-child nodes.)

Although I found this example by hand, I often turn to computer assistance.